# IError CS1003 Unity?

Tags: c#

```
using UnityEngine;

public class MouseCam : MonoBehaviour 
{   
     public float mouseSensitivity = 100f;

        public transform playerBody;
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start() 
    {

    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update() 
    {
        float mouseX = Input.GetAxis(Mouse X) * mouseSensitivity * Time.deltaTime;

        float mouseY = Input.GetAxis(Mouse Y) * mouseSensitivity * Time.deltaTime;

        playerBody.Rotate(Vector3.up * mouseX);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`public transform playerBody` should be `public Transform playerBody` with upper case T.